# AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_DATA_DISCONTINUITY sometimes set, sometimes not

Tags: c++, audio, windows-phone-8, wasapi

I try to make a simple VoIP app for windows phone8 using WASAPI.In some run of the project By Calling

```
hr = m_pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pbData, &nFrames, &dwFlags, nullptr, nullptr)
```

after some minutes dwFlags repeatedly set to 1 (AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_DATA_DISCONTINUITY) and returned packet become smaller and smaller and stutter become more and more during the time but in some run of the project everything is fine and the voice is completely clear.

Can anybody help about it?

```
  //MAX_RAW_BUFFER_SIZE 320

     void BackEndAudio::CaptureThread(Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction^ operation)
{
    uint8_t amrEncodedData[13];
    uint8_t SendingData[14];
    HRESULT hr = m_pDefaultCaptureDevice->Start();
    BYTE *pLocalBuffer = new BYTE[MAX_RAW_BUFFER_SIZE];
    HANDLE eventHandles[] = {
                             hCaptureEvent,        // WAIT_OBJECT0 
                             hShutdownEvent        // WAIT_OBJECT0 + 1
                            };

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pLocalBuffer)  
    { 
        unsigned int uAccumulatedBytes = 0;
        while (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            DWORD waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(SIZEOF_ARRAY(eventHandles), eventHandles, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);
             if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == waitResult)
            {
                BYTE* pbData = nullptr;
                UINT32 nFrames = 0;
                DWORD dwFlags = 0;
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {

                    hr = m_pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pbData, &nFrames, &dwFlags, nullptr, nullptr);//Retrieves a pointer to the next available packet of data in the capture endpoint buffer. 

                    unsigned int incomingBufferSize = nFrames * m_sourceFrameSizeInBytes;
                    if (*SendFrameNo==(uint8_t)256) 
                        *SendFrameNo=0;
                    if(dwFlags==1)
                        glitch++;
                        while(MAX_RAW_BUFFER_SIZE - uAccumulatedBytes < incomingBufferSize)
                        {

                            memcpy(pLocalBuffer + uAccumulatedBytes, pbData,MAX_RAW_BUFFER_SIZE-uAccumulatedBytes);

                            if (transportController)
                            {
                                short *tempbuffer=new short[160];
                                for(int i=0;i<160;i++)
                                {
                                    BToS.buf[0]=pLocalBuffer[i*2];
                                    BToS.buf[1]=pLocalBuffer[i*2+1];
                                    tempbuffer[i]=BToS.shbuf;
                                }
                                bool bRet = EasyVAD_IsSilence(hVAD,tempbuffer,160);
                                if(!bRet)
                                {
                                    Encoder_Interface_Encode(amren, MR475, (const short *)pLocalBuffer, amrEncodedData, 0);
                                    memcpy(SendingData,SendFrameNo,1);
                                    memcpy(SendingData+1,amrEncodedData,13);
                                    transportController->Write(SendingData, 14);
                                    (*SendFrameNo)++;
                                }

                            }
                            pbData+=(MAX_RAW_BUFFER_SIZE-uAccumulatedBytes);
                            incomingBufferSize-=(MAX_RAW_BUFFER_SIZE-uAccumulatedBytes);
                            uAccumulatedBytes=0;
                        }

                    if(MAX_RAW_BUFFER_SIZE - uAccumulatedBytes == incomingBufferSize)
                    {
                        memcpy(pLocalBuffer + uAccumulatedBytes, pbData, incomingBufferSize);
                        if (transportController)
                        {
                            short *tempbuffer=new short[160];
                            for(int i=0;i<160;i++)
                                {
                                    BToS.buf[0]=pLocalBuffer[i*2];
                                    BToS.buf[1]=pLocalBuffer[i*2+1];
                                    tempbuffer[i]=BToS.shbuf;
                                }
                                bool bRet = EasyVAD_IsSilence(hVAD,tempbuffer,160);
                                if(!bRet)
                                {
                                    Encoder_Interface_Encode(amren, MR475, (const short *)pLocalBuffer, amrEncodedData, 0);
                                    memcpy(SendingData,SendFrameNo,1);
                                    memcpy(SendingData+1,amrEncodedData,13);
                                    transportController->Write(SendingData, 14);
                                    (*SendFrameNo)++;
                                }

                        }
                        // Reset our counter
                        uAccumulatedBytes = 0;
                    }
                    else if(MAX_RAW_BUFFER_SIZE - uAccumulatedBytes > incomingBufferSize)
                    {
                        memcpy(pLocalBuffer + uAccumulatedBytes, pbData, incomingBufferSize);
                        uAccumulatedBytes += incomingBufferSize;
                    }

                }

                 if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = m_pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(nFrames);
                }
            }
            else if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 == waitResult)
            {
                // We're being asked to shutdown
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Unknown return value
                DbgRaiseAssertionFailure();
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] pLocalBuffer;
}
```

I know that the code does to much work between each `GetBuffer` call and this is probably the main issue of time glitches  but my question is why sometimes it happens and sometimes not?

Comment: What I suspect is taking place is that you are too slow taking buffers from capture client. It has an internal overflow somewhere on the way and hence the flag and data corruption you experience during capture sessions. Comment out your `EasyVAD_IsSilence` and `transportController->Write` stuff to run a clean capture session, see if you have it working fine then. This might explain your previous questions as well.

Comment: I noticed that time glitch in 8KHz/1Channel/16bit format (By sending a undocumented parameter to AudioClient initialize) occurs much more than the 48KHz/2Channel/32bit format.I'm trying use the 48Khz format and then re-sample it for encoding. I will comment the results as soon as get to it.

Comment: I finally choose 48KHz sampling and use libsamplerate to re-sample it to 8KHz.Now time glitch is much less than before.I don't know why but it is.

Comment: `1` this supports my suspicion above `2` there should be Microsoft MFT for resampling available as well (not sure about Windows Phone 8, but I would expect it to be there).